# Spring web service publishment performance on deploy time

Tags: java, spring, performance, web-services, deployment

I've confronted with a performance problem whilst deploying a war file to Glassfish AS.
after inspecting Glassfish's log acquires that the web services are contribute to this issue.
as a matter of fact it takes so long to publish web services at deploying occasion.

caution : this web services are provided by Spring framework

you might prefer to see this chunk of glassfish's log :

- [#|2014-07-06T09:30:05.690+0430|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ryService,pdImportHistoryService,cmsApplicationService,applicationTemplateService,cardTransactionService,userHistoryService,acceptanceTableService,rootUserService,productRequestService,importDataFromPD,batchService,productTemplateService,productService,acceptanceNetworkService,acceptanceNetworkTypeService,branchUserWS,personalizerWS,contactWS,contactPropertyWS]; root of factory hierarchy
  |#]
- [#|2014-07-06T09:30:16.264+0430|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|31767 [admin-thread-pool-4848(3)] INFO  org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean  - Creating Service {http://webservice.business.core.cms.tosan.com/}ApplicationWebServiceService from class com.tosan.cms.biz.service.ApplicationManager
  |#]
- [#|2014-07-06T09:30:20.967+0430|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|36470 [admin-thread-pool-4848(3)] INFO  org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl  - Setting the server's publish address to be /ApplicationManager
- 
- 
- ...publishing rest of web services...

as you might noticed it takes 15secs from begining this process to publishing earliest web service.
in addition it worth to mention publishing remained web services takes 16 more seconds.
now the questions are: 
1. why it takes too long to publish this web services?
2. may I find any solution to enahnce this time to a reasonable amount?

best regards
mh.saeedi

Comment: what's your deployment environment?

Comment: unfortunately Your enquiery has a little vagueness to me nevertheless this might aid :deployment is getting done under glassfish-3.1 in development env and we used   ui:gwt|ws:soap|biz:spring|dao:hibernate/jpa |